# Can't create new projects nor items: Visual Studio 2010 dialog initialization exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I do Add>New Item, Add>New Project or File>New Project VS2010 is throwing a dialog initialization exception, preventing me from creating new projects or classes. Any idea on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you might have a problem related to a third party package or add-in.  Here are some things to try:

- Running Visual Studio as an administrator.
- You can try running `devenv /Resetsettings` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)) in a Command Prompt which
  should fix any corrupted settings
- Try running `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` (see
  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276.aspx))
  which will avoid loading any problem packages.
- Try running `devenv /Safemode` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)).  If it works in safe mode then the
  problem is most likely a third party add-ins or package.
- You can also try `Devenv.exe /log <log path>"`.  This will generate a file called `ActivityLog.xml` which might give you further clues.

If none of those help then *repair* Visual Studio from the Control Panel.

Comment: Your answer came one minute too late :) I repaired, and it worked, but I'd rather have tried those solutions beforehand. They'll be handy should any such thing happen again. I ran VS as administrator, and I reset the settings, albeit not from the command line but from inside VS. The other ones I didn't try.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on my computer and after a long time spent searching, I solved it by doing the following:

- Close all instances of Visual Studio 2010
- Open the terminal and go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` (depending on your VS installation directory).
- Run command: `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` and wait until will be finished.
- Run Visual Studio.

Comment: I did what you said and VS2015 is working for me!! Thanks a lot!! I did not have to reinstall VS!