# Can't create or open web applications

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013 Pro and having big problems. Opening an exsiting Web application and creating new web applications throws errors, rendering VS completely useless.

I will try to describe the problems, details about what might be causing the problem and what I've tried to fix the problem.

**The problems**

1) When I try to open an existing web application, I get an error saying:

Creation of the virtual directory `http://localhost:1234/` failed with the error: Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.

2) When I try to create a new web application, I get an error saying:

Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

**Details**

During the weekend the internal IT department, made a change to the network. The "My Documents" folder i stored on a network drive. The IT department changed the path of the "My Documents" folder. Visual Studio has some setting files which are stored in "My Documents" and it might not have updated the path to the folder, causing the error.

**What I have tried**

- Ran Visual Studio as Administrator
- Repaired Visual Studio from "Add/remove programs"
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio
- Uninstalled Resharper
- Tried this [Can't create new projects nor items: Visual Studio 2010 dialog initialization exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225637/cant-create-new-projects-nor-items-visual-studio-2010-dialog-initialization-ex)
- Running c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga ASPNET (gave the error: An error has occurred: 0x800706fc The trust relationship between the primary dom
  ain and the trusted domain failed.)

Nothing has fixed the problem. Please heeeeelp!!!

Comment: try this in command prompt c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga ASPNET; or try to disable windows UAC.

Comment: Tried it, but that threw an error. I added the error in the post above.

Comment: Try to do this: Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security - > Windows Authentication ->Click the checkbox and install. and after tray to run again the command

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I had already installed all the components under IIS.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

`Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off... inside that, we had to select Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS 6 Management Compatibility -> IIS Metabse and IIS 6 configuration compatibility`.

**Solution 2:**

Edit the web application's project file with a text editor and change this line from True to False:

```
<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
```

**Solution 3:**

Grant IIS AppPool identity permissions to the `%systemroot%\inetsrv\config`

**Solution 4:**

run in command prompt:
`aspnet_regiis -i` or `aspnet_regiis.exe -ga`

Comment: I've tried 1, 2 and 4, but this still hasn't solved the issue. Solution 3 I cannot try, because I do not have the specified directory. Could this be the culprit?