# not able to open new project in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Every time I tried to open the new project, this error was thrown:

> New project/item dialog could not be initialized due to error: Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogInitializationException'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create new projects nor items: Visual Studio 2010 dialog initialization exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225637/cant-create-new-projects-nor-items-visual-studio-2010-dialog-initialization-ex)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open run command using <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`
3. Click OK

[image: Open run (it's a desktop app) . and write this devenv.exe /resetuserdata]

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problems and fixed it. First you need to open command prompt for shortcout Windows key+r (run command dialog box) and write here : devenv.exe /resetuserdata   and press enter. Hope the problems will be fixed. If you face any problems again you can knock me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Go to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"
3. Run command `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`
4. Run Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Close all instances of Visual Studio
Go to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"
Run command devenv.exe /resetuserdata
Run Visual Studio