# I can not open any project/item in visual studio 2015, and the error is shown "microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogInitializationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, android-applicationinfo

I can not open any project/item in visual studio 2015, and the error is as follows:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogInitializationException

What can I do to solve this problem and error? It happened after installing Zamarin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create new projects nor items: Visual Studio 2010 dialog initialization exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225637/cant-create-new-projects-nor-items-visual-studio-2010-dialog-initialization-ex)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below:

1. Run Visual Studio as an administrator.
2. Run `devenv /Resetsettings` in Command Prompt. This will resolve corrupted settings.
3. Repair Visual Studio in the Control Panel.